# Workbench in SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1054

**Query:**

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, customer_id FROM sakila.customer JOIN sakila.rental USING (rental_id) LIMIT 0, 1000;
```

Error Message:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'rental_id' in 'from clause'   0.0022 sec
```

The column exist but says its unknown

Comment: Since you're doing `JOIN USING`, the column should exist in both the tables.

Comment: sharing your table structure would be helpful

Comment: Do both the tables have column rental_id with same name in both the tables? Because `USING` is useful when both tables share a column of the exact same name on which they join

Comment: The customer table in the sakila sample database does not contain a rental_id column.